# where is indigo rqt source

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, rqt, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using ubuntu 14.04 and indigo devel. I am trying to build rqt from the source and on the github [link], it doesn't have indigo branch, so where can I download the rqt for indigo from the source?(https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt)

Also, I noticed there are a lot of package source does not have an indigo branch, such as rqt and qt_gui_core, etc. So, what should I do if I need the indigo source files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289917/where-is-indigo-rqt-source/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Repositories might not have branches for each an every ROS version. Sometimes the same code is being used for different ROS distributions and then only a single branch (commonly with the name of the older ROS distro) exists.

You can find the information you are looking for by look into the [rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro) database. In the [Indigo distribution file](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/indigo/distribution.yaml) you will find an entry for `rqt` which specifies the URL and branch name to be used in that ROS distro: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/df65c25ff7445aa818953c1e778fffabedb4f3d6/indigo/distribution.yaml#L13013-L13033

So the branch you are looking for is `groovy-devel`:

```
rqt:
  doc:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt.git
    version: groovy-devel
  release:
    packages:
    - rqt
    - rqt_gui
    - rqt_gui_cpp
    - rqt_gui_py
    - rqt_py_common
    tags:
      release: release/indigo/{package}/{version}
    url: https://github.com/ros-gbp/rqt-release.git
    version: 0.4.8-0
  source:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt.git
    version: groovy-devel
  status: maintained
```

---

As an alternative you could also use `rosinstall_generator` to fetch the information for you:

> rosinstall_generator --rosdistro indigo rqt --upstream-development

```
- git:
    local-name: rqt
    uri: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt.git
    version: groovy-devel
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-04-28**:
Thank you!